# There is not connect another profile in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, application.properties, java-16

I have a project with two properties.

- application.yml (major)

```yaml
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: local
  application:
    name: test-app
  datasource:
    cluster:
      enabled: true
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 30
      minimum-idle: 3
      autoCommit: false
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        connection.provider_disables_autocommit: true
        jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation: true
      open-in-view: false
```

- application-local.yml

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    read:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test-app
    write:
      url:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/test-app
    username:
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
    open-in-view: false
```

I also have added the setting in **IntelliJ IDEA**

[image]

VM options also has used.

-Dspring.profiles.active=local

But during the launch I get an error:

> Description:
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and
> no embedded datasource could be configured.

> Reason: Failed to determine suitable jdbc url

I assume that the specified profile did not start

Who has any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: During startup, there sould be a log line similar to `The following profiles are active: X, Y, Z`, which will at least tell you if `local` is being activated.

Comment: @ekalin: No, I didn't find anything like that

Comment: The problem was in the syntax of the *-local.yml file